# python pymongo not raising exceptions for "Unknown modifier:"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Tried to update a mongo document using update query in robomongo client

```
db.test.update({"name": "test"},{"$kset": {"value": "test_value"}})
```

and it returned the following exception 
**Unknown modifier: $kset** which is expected, but running the same query using pymongo is not ending in exception, instead it is returning None.

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10

pymongo (2.8)

```
import pymongo
uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
client = pymongo.Connection(uri)["test"]
client.test.update({"name": "test"},{"$kset": {"value": "test_value"}})
```

Why pymongo is not returning such exceptions bydefault?

Comment: in mongo shell 3.0.12 i get an `errmsg: Unknown modifier: $kset`

Comment: Where is python code?

Comment: updated python code.

Comment: problem is solved by adding "safe=True" during mongo connection,
we can either use "safe=True" or "j=True" (j=journal) 
`client = pymongo.Connection(uri, safe=True)["test"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PyMongo 2.8+, the use of [pymongo.Connection](http://api.mongodb.com/python/2.8/api/pymongo/connection.html#module-pymongo.connection) has been deprecated.

Instead you should be using [pymongo.MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.com/python/2.8/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html). If you use `MongoClient` in your code as in:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)["test"]
```

You should be getting an OperationFailure exception, similar to below:

```
raise OperationFailure(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unknown modifier: $kset
```

Also note that [MongoDB v2.6 has reached end of life October 2016](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life), you may want to upgrade to current stable release i.e. [MongoDB v3.2](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center)

See also [Python Driver Compatibility versions](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/python/#python-driver-compatibility).